# Snow Leopard 10.6.7 - Lost all Dock icons except "finder" and "trash"

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I've read all the "how-to" solutions on the icon/dock problem. However, when I drag the applications folder to the dock area it does not stay there. When I double-click and application, then ctrl-click the apps icon, I do not get the "keep in dock" option choice -- only "open at login" and "show in finder".

I'm new to Mac, but this seems to be a deeper problem...

Answer (score 0):

From the Desktop/Finder:

Go > Home > Library > Preferences > find any files named like com.apple.dock.plist and move them to the trash, then restart.  OS X should rebuild this file and allow you to customize the dock as you wish.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2798158?start=0&tstart=0

Once you have done this also be sure to run Software Update and install any updates listed.